# selecting item from primeface's selectOneMenu not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I'm having problem with getting the selected item from a `selectOneMenu`.
Here is my JSF code:

```
<h:form id="mainfrm">   
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5">  
        <h:outputText value="Basic Usage: " />  
        <p:selectOneMenu id="domaine" value="#{projet.currentDomaines}">  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />  
            <f:selectItems value="#{projet.initDomaines()}"  var="d" itemValue="#{d}" itemLabel="#{d.libelleDomaine}" /> 
            <p:ajax update="formEquipe" process="mainfrm" event="change" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
     </h:panelGrid>     

</h:form>  

<h:form id="formEquipe">  
    <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4">  
        <f:facet name="header">  
            <p:graphicImage value="/images/cars/xxxx.jpg"/>  
        </f:facet>  

        <h:outputText value="Domaine name :" />  
        <h:outputText value="#{projet.currentDomaines.libelleDomaine}"/>  

        <h:outputText value="Director :" />  
        <h:outputText value="#{projet.currentDomaines.nomDirecteur}" />  
    </h:panelGrid>  
</h:form>
```

it seems like everything is right but i must be missing something... so i tested by changing the currentDomaines (object type Domaines) by text (String) and it worked, and here is the code :

```
<h:form id="mainfrm">   
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5">  
        <h:outputText value="Basic Usage: " />  
        <p:selectOneMenu id="domaine" value="#{projet.text}">  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />  
            <f:selectItems value="#{projet.initDomaines()}"  var="d" itemValue="#{d.libelleDomaine}" itemLabel="#{d.libelleDomaine}" /> 
            <p:ajax update="formEquipe" process="mainfrm" event="change" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </h:panelGrid>     
</h:form>  

<h:form id="formEquipe">  
    <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4">  
        <f:facet name="header">  
        <p:graphicImage value="/images/cars/xxxx.jpg"/>  
        </f:facet>  

        <h:outputText value="Domaine name :" />  
        <h:outputText value="#{projet.text/>  
    </h:panelGrid>  
</h:form>
```

and here is my backing bean:

```
public class ProjetsBean implements Serializable {

   private  DomainesService domainesService;

   private Domaines currentDomaines;
   private String text;


   /////////////// setters & getters \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
   public void setCurrentDomaines(Domaines currentDomaines) {
       this.currentDomaines=currentDomaines;
   }
   public Domaines getCurrentDomaines() {
       return currentDomaines;
   }

   public void setText(String text) {
       this.text=text;
   }
   public Integer getText() {
       return text;
   }

   ///////////////// Méthodes  \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
   @PostConstruct   
   public List<Domaines> initDomaines() {
       return domainesService.getAllDomaines();
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The selection from a html selectbox will always be returned to the server as string. If you want to use objects in `h:selectOneMenu` you need a converter.

There is a comprehensive tutorial on that topic: ["Objects in h:selectOneMenu"](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/09/objects-in-hselectonemenu.html).

Answer (score -1):

For the most cases you can do it without an converter, but this is not wrong.

Here is an example:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectedObject.id}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.listOfObjects}" var="item" itemLabel="#{item.title}" itemValue="#{item.id}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Another idea is to use the hashcode instead of the ID (but in both: itemValue and value).

Comment: This particular example only changes the ID of the selected object, this does not change the selected object itself nor any of its other properties. This will end up in major trouble in object based persistence layer such as JPA unless you manually replace the selected object afterwards. Your example would be more valid if you used `#{bean.selectedObjectId}` instead.